# PowerShell: get variable from "for each"

Tags: powershell, foreach

There is only one MSI file in folder $DS_Folder.
I need to have it as variable $MSI
My not working script:

```
Foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $DS_Folder){
If ($file.extension -eq ".msi") {$MSI=$file.FullName}
}
Write-Host $MSI
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: $MSI returns nothing if file exists

Comment: Your code snippet works for me. Have you verified all your the assumptions ?  (e.g. that you're in the directory you think you are, that $DS_Folder has the proper value, etc. ?)

Comment: Have you made sure that your variable is properly scoped?